# box-shadow on the wrong place translateZ

Tags: css, transform

This is my first question as i didn't find any answer about why it does it or how to work around with this.

I have an item (.top) over a .base but the shadow does not looks good. 
It look like the shadow is created where the element .top is. How can i project the shadow of .top on the .base element?

Thank you all :)

```js
//for test purpose

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
 var mouseX = e.clientX/window.innerWidth*2-1;
 document.querySelector(".base").style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%) rotateY("+-mouseX*90+"deg)"
})
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #eee;
}
.base{
 position: absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: white;
 backface-visibility: visible;
 -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform: 
  translate(-50%,-50%);
 
}
.top{
 
 position: absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border-radius:50%;
 
 background-color: blue;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform: 
  translate(-50%,-50%)
  translateZ(20px);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 4px #aaa;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
   <section class="top"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to achieve in terms of perspective or shadow.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I want to have the shadow on .top projected on .base. Like in reality, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the shadow effect to a pseudo element on the `.base`, rather than a shadow on the `.top` element:

```js
//for test purpose

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var mouseX = e.clientX / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;
  document.querySelector(".base").style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%) rotateY(" + -mouseX * 90 + "deg)"
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.base {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.base:after {
  content: "";
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  left: 80px;
  top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 8px 8px #aaa;
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  transform: translateZ(1px);
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translateZ(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <section class="top"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is a great work around ! So it is a normal behavior for box-shadow i guess...